# separate list of parameter into different file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script with 2 funtions:

```
function Stonebrach.Connect {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    $Body
)

$basicAuth=Get-Content "C:\$auth_filename"
$headers = @{
        "Authorization" = $basicAuth
        "Content-Type"="application/json"
}
$RSP=$null

try{
    if ( $body -eq $null ) {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $Sb_uri -Method $Method -Headers $headers
    }
    else {
        $response = invoke-restmethod -Uri $sb_uri -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body $body
    }
    return $response
}
catch{
   $RSP = $_.Exception.Message
   return $RSP
}
}

function Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Sb_base_uri,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Auth_filename,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Method,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Body
)
    Stonebrach.Connect -SB_uri $Sb_base_uri/task -Auth_filename $Auth_filename -Method $Method -Body $Body
```

}

the body param is hardcoded as below:

```
$body = '
{
"type" : "taskWindows",
"actions" : {
  "abortActions" : [],
  "emailNotifications" : [],
  "setVariableActions" : [],
  "snmpNotifications" : [],
  "systemOperations" : []
},
"agent" : "test",
"name" : "Test Create",
"summary" : "Test Create"
}
'
```

Call the function:

```
$response = Stonebranch.Create.Task.Windows -Sb_base_uri $Sb_base_uri -Auth_filename $Auth_filename -Method POST -Body $body
```

Here's the question: **i want to separate the $body into a different file (prefer YAML file)**. Anyone know how to separate and pass the list of param to the script so i can use them? I find it hard to pass the list of param and call the function.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like . ("$ScriptDirectory\IncludeFile.ps1")

Comment: im not sure i understand what you mean sir. I tried to google what you write, but nothing link to my question. Can you tell in more details?

Comment: You want to outsource the body-part in a different file and use them in your script? That was my understanding. You can do this with . ("$ScriptDirectory\IncludeBodyPart.ps1") Watch the point before!